# How to change the value of a public variable which is defined in a servlet in another jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is the Servlet.

```
public class Booksearcher extends HttpServlet {

    private static Connection conn = ConnManager.getInstance().getConnection();
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int flag=0;
```

This is the jsp file in which i am trying to change the value of 'flag' variable.

```
<title>Cart</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Booksearcher.flag=1;
%>
```

Eclipse gives the following error.

```
An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /addedtocart.jsp
Booksearcher cannot be resolved to a variable
10: </head>
11: <body>
12: <%
13: Booksearcher.flag=1;
14: %>
15: <h3>Successfully added to cart</h3>
16: <a href="Homepage.jsp">Go to previous page</a>
```

Comment: Are you getting this error at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do , but servlet have to be stateless class, if you want to use a static variable inside jsp then is better to use a pojo java class.

Comment: I think you have to import the class inside the jsp

Comment: I am trying to import the class using page directive.But then also error is coming.Can you give an example of how to import class??

Comment: <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified name of the class. That includes the package name.

```
your.package.Booksearcher.flag=1;
```

Comment: after adding the package name,i am having this problem "package name cannot be resolved to a variable"